# Center a button under 3 divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs (colored squares) and a button.

How can I center the button under the divs?

With my current code the button appears in the same line as `#squares` and it's floating to the left. Thanks for your answers.

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#squares {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 35%;
}
#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="squares">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
<div id="button">
  <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using flexbox, there are multiple solutions, all of them relatively simple.

Here's one:

- Wrap both containers in a parent container.
- Add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to this new container.
- Now you can easily align the squares and the button both vertically and horizontally.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#squares {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#button {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="squares">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="button">
    <button>Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you are using `position: absolute` for the square-container?

If not, you can just make the position relative, recenter the content and center the button.

**Important code changes**:

```
#squares {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

#button {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/q17fa25w/

Answer (score 0):

Other way to solve it, you can set ***padding*** left and top for ***#button*** div like this:

```
#button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 120px 35%;
}
```